# Loading existing oracle database in memory JAVA

Tags: java, oracle, derby

I am trying to figure out how it would be possible to load existing oracle database in memory on Unit test. Are there any ways to accomplish that? I read about Apache Derby but unfortunately cannot find an answer about how to use exported file to load the existing DB in memory. Any ideas? Thank you for you answer.

**Why do I need it? To not populate the database with corrupted / fictitious results.**

Comment: Oracle offers a [Database In-Memory option](https://www.oracle.com/database/database-in-memory/index.html) with 12c.

Comment: What is your unit test trying to test? You might be approaching this the wrong way. You could also set up a regular test database that's accessible to the unit tests, although this sounds more like something needed for *integration* tests and not unit tests.

Comment: Please guys don't analyze the needs. I am just trying to find a way to create temporary/in memory database from existing one for unit tests. Check guys updated answer.

Comment: To be clear: what you are talking about is loading Oracle data structures into  RAM from an export file, and not populating DB buffer cache with the complete contents of a database.

Comment: It should be optional but both facilities should be available. cause I want [ to test with existing records / new records or even empty table ]

Comment: You're not supposed to run any tests against your production database, so you don't have to worry about populating the db with "corrupted / fictitious results". Just create another DB in oracle and use that. We analyze your needs to give you the best possible answer, if you don't want that then don't post questions here.

Comment: It is not efficient my friend. The connection has long latency cause the requests are quite big and server is not located in the office where I work. + again you have to grant the right permissions to users and etc. It is way better to have kind of temporary database for tests. This is the best practise.

Comment: Okay sir. Any solution? Any software/jars?

Comment: Can you even fit the db in memory? You're probably not the first person trying to move data from Oracle to Derby, so do some searching.

Answer (score 0):

To load data into a Derby database from a CSV file, try the SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE system procedure: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/rrefimportproc.html

And to control whether a Derby database exists only in memory, or persists on disk, you specify `jdbc:derby:memory:` in the JDBC Connection URL: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/devguide/cdevdvlpinmemdb.html